# Why can't my SQL Service start after i've changed it from Disabled -> Automatic via the registry

Tags: registry

When I change the registry from Disabled

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\Start\ = 4`

to Automatic

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\Start\ = 2`

and when I try to start the service, I now get the error:

> Windows could not start the SQL Server (MSSQL) service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 1058: The service cannot be started, either because it is
>   disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

When I refresh the services box it shows up as 'Automatic' and allows me to press `Start`

Am I missing something else?

The reason I am doing it from the registry is because I am making a 'service start up type checker' and this was the easiest way with permissions to do it.

---

edit: I changed it via the actual services box and compared the reg settings and couldn't see a difference.